# Link to .XSL file from a .HTML file

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am sure this is real easy and I am just missing something simple but...

I have a home page (index.html) and I want to link to another page that is an .xsl file (to show some xml data). I am using this code to do it:

```
<h1><a href="catalogue_overview.xsl">VIEW CATALOGUE</a></h1>
```

When I open the .xsl file by itself (I use Dreamweaver) it opens and displays the data (from the xml file) fine.

When I open it from the link on the index.html page it just shows me the unformatted text contained in the `<h>` and `<p>` tags etc. There is no formatiing and no xml data.

What am I doing wrong?

Do I need to tell the index.html file something so it knows about the .xsl file?

Am I doing this wrong?

I am linking to a PHP file the same way and that seems to work fine.

I will post my code in case that helps!

### XML FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="catalogue_overview.xsl"?>

<catalogue>
    <record>
        <catId>001</catId>
        <title>Fungus</title>
        <location>NP</location>
        <photographer>Me</photographer>
        <equipment>Canon EOS 40D</equipment>
        <caption>Small fungus of the genus Fungaroidiae on a log</caption>
        <notes>This is a very rare species of fungus</notes>
        <date>10/8/2012</date>
        <imageUrl>images/IMG_1684.jpg</imageUrl>
    </record>
</catalogue>
```

### XSL FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!-- DWXMLSource="catalogue.xml" -->

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:template match="catalogue">
    <html> 
      <head> 
        <title>Photo Catalogue</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>

     </head>
     <body>

     <h1 align="center"> Photo Catalogue</h1>
     <h2 align="center"> Catalogue Overview </h2>
     <p align="center"> This is an overview of the photo catalogue. It enables the user to have a quick and easy browse through the images and their information.</p>
     <hr/>

      <xsl:apply-templates/>

     </body>
    </html>

   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="catId">
        <h2> Catalogue ID: <span style="color:2A588F"><xsl:apply-templates/>  </span> </h2>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="title">
        <h3> Title: <span style="color:2A588F"><xsl:apply-templates/>  </span> </h3>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="location">
        <p> Location: <span style="color:2A588F"><xsl:apply-templates/>  </span> </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="photographer">
        <p> Photographer: <span style="color:2A588F"><xsl:apply-templates/>  </span> </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="equipment">
        <p> Equipment: <span style="color:2A588F"><xsl:apply-templates/>  </span> </p>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="caption">
        <p> Caption: <span style="color:2A588F"><xsl:apply-templates/>  </span> </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="notes">
        <p> Notes: <span style="color:2A588F"><xsl:apply-templates/>  </span> </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="date">
        <p> Date: <span style="color:2A588F"><xsl:apply-templates/>  </span> </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="imageUrl">
        <p>Image:<br/><img src="{.}" width="250"/></p>
        <hr/>
    </xsl:template>


 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

### INDEX.HTML FILE

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Photo Catalogue - HOME</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/


</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="content">
    <h1>Photo Catalogue</h1>
    <h2>Welcome to the Photo Catalogue</h2>
    <p>It is intended to be a simple tool to store you favourite photos for easy viewing. It uses XML to store the image details and this is retrieved, displayed and edited using a combination of XSL and PHP.</p>
    <h2>Navigation</h2>
    <p>Select the option you would like below to see its functionality...</p>

    <h1><a href="catalogue_overview.xsl">VIEW CATALOGUE</a></h1>
    <h1><a href="catalogueupdate.php">EDIT CATALOGUE</a></h1>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps

NOTE the link to the .php file seems to work fine. I am running off XAMPP.

Thanks

Comment: the xsl defines the display\rendering of the xml file, you don't link to it directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should link to the XML file of which the data should be rendered. This means in your INDEX.HTML change

```
<h1><a href="catalogue_overview.xsl">VIEW CATALOGUE</a></h1>
```

to

```
<h1><a href="catalogue.xml">VIEW CATALOGUE</a></h1>
```

The XML file then does refer to the XSL stylesheet through

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="catalogue_overview.xsl"?>
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I new it was something simple.